# how to get context of current router

Tags: ember.js

Sometimes I need to rerender all view and call `App.router.connectOutlet`, but I dont have context to pass to this method.

The first parameter router I set as `App.router`, but there is problem with the second.

Is there any way to get it?

**EDIT**:

```
Ember.Route.extend( {
  home : Ember.Route.extend( {
    route : '/:cat_id',
    connectOutlets : function(router, context) {
      // ...
    },
    doFooterService : function( router, event ) {
      App.router.transitionTo( 'home', {
        cat_id : event.view.content.id
      });
    },
  },
  // ...
}
```

And sometimes I have to manualy call connectOutlets function to rerender page. I want no to go somewhere else, but just rerender this view with other param. But I don't know what should pass as context param.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking. Can you add some code to your question and point out what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What is your purpose?? You should never have to call this function yourself. Did you try simply `transitionTo` same route?

Comment: calling transitionTo twice has no effect. Ember doesn't do anything in this csse. Why I cant call this method? I want to refresh currently used controller with new value

Comment: I still don't know what you're trying to do. What's your end goal here? Can you just explain briefly what you're trying to achieve? And no, you can't transition to the current route, Ember won't reload it like that.

Comment: On application start I call rest to get User with his group IDs. But in router in functions connectOutlets I call other rest methods which needs this one of this ID. 
I add Observer to selected ID (exacly to Ember.Select) and when it change I call connectOutlets on currentState of router.

I'm simply new in this technology and probably I do lots of bugs and apply wrong patterns to my App